# Website getting slow image requests in apache using PHP

Tags: php, apache

This is strange, and I couldn't find any way to fix it or debug it.

When I'm using my website, that show images using php file (I access them, and resize/extract information and show) It's ok for a couple of minutes. After that, the images requests (that are done with php) are getting slower, but if I decide to open only the image on the browser, it works fast.

If I switch to another domain that also redirect to the same website, it works fast again.

Could this be because of the browser settings ? apache settings ?

My configuration is Apache 2 + PHP + MySQL + Postgres.

Comment: could just be your internet connection, could be anything

Comment: @developerwjk, is in my local network. I think the problem is the browser, but could be some configuration not be set up properly. But, because is so strange I will start track the loading times of the php script that show images, to see if on the client side or server side.

Answer (score 0):

Put profiling code in your php code; i.e. manually put time measurements of before and after sections of code. Narrow down to section of code that gets slow. If no such section appears, then it is something else.

You could also use something like newRelic. It would auto profile the code for you and help you narrow down the problem